# How to refactor angularjs controllers with mostly common code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring, ng-controller

I'm relatively new to angularjs. I've got some code (HTML + JS) that allows a user to add and remove entries from an in-scope array. Right now however I am massively repeating code for different arrays. I know this can be re-factored but I'm not sure of the angular approach, other than the fact that I'll probably want to use a directive. Any help greatly appreciated.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.profile.seeking.$invalid}" ng-controller="SeekingCtrl">
    <label class="control-label" for="profile.seeking">Seeking</label>
<div class="controls">
    <ul ng-repeat="seeks in profile.seeking">
      <li>{{seeks}} <button class="btn" ng-click="removeSeeks()">Remove</button></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newseeks" id="profile.seeking">
    <button class="btn" ng-disabled="!newseeks" ng-click="addSeeks()">Add new</button>
</div>
```

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.project.offering.$invalid}" ng-controller="OfferingCtrl">
<label class="control-label" for="project.offering">Offering</label>
<div class="controls">
    <ul ng-repeat="offer in project.offering">
      <li>{{offer}} <button class="btn" ng-click="removeOffer()">Remove</button></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newoffer" id="project.offering">
    <button class="btn" ng-disabled="!newoffer" ng-click="addOffer()">Add new</button>
</div>
```

**The Javascript**

```
var SeekingCtrl = function($scope) {
$scope.addSeeks = function() {
    $scope.profile.seeking = $scope.profile.seeking || [];
    $scope.profile.seeking.push($scope.newseeks);
    $scope.newseeks = "";
};

$scope.removeSeeks = function() {
    $scope.profile.seeking = _.without($scope.profile.seeking, this.seeks);
};
};

var OfferingCtrl = function($scope) {
$scope.addOffer = function() {
    $scope.project.offers = $scope.project.offers || [];
    $scope.project.offers.push($scope.newoffer);
    $scope.newoffer = "";
};

$scope.removeOffer = function() {
    $scope.project.offers = _.without($scope.project.offers, this.offer);
};
};
```

Comment: Place the code that is used by more than one controller in a Serviceclass, typically called service.js in angular. And inject the service in your controller.

Comment: Thanks @TorAndersson. I'm looking for a little more detail if possible, regarding the actual 'how'. I know about services, I use them elsewhere. Right now, I'm just stuck on _how_ to use a service. What would it look like? How would I ensure the correct array was updated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally figured this out.

**The HTML**

```
<div list-editor list="profile.skills" label="Skills">
</div>
```

**The Directive**

```
<div class="control-group" ng-controller="ListEditorCtrl">
    <label class="control-label" for="{{list}}">{{label}}</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in list">
        <li>{{item}} 
            <button class="btn" ng-click="removeItem()"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
            <button class="btn" ng-show="!$first" ng-click="moveUpItem()"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></button>
            <button class="btn" ng-show="!$last" ng-click="moveDownItem()"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newitem" id="{{list}}" />
    <button class="btn" ng-disabled="!newitem" ng-click="addItem()">Add new</button>
</div>
```

```
p4pApp.directive('listEditor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            list: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '/templates/common/list_editor_directive.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.label;
        }
    };
}
);
```

**The Controller**

```
var ListEditorCtrl = function($scope) {
$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.list = $scope.list || [];
    $scope.list.push($scope.newitem);
    $scope.newitem = "";
};

$scope.removeItem = function() {
    $scope.list.splice(_.indexOf($scope.list, this.item),1);
};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear enough for me it would be better if you put a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3510140) with an example code that would be easier to understand, but i'll try to answer from what I understand.
In you services.js file do something like this:

```
app.factory('Seeks', ['$http', function($http){
  var Url  = "seeks.json";
  var Seeks = $http.get(Url).then(function(response){
     return response.data;
  });
  return Seeks;
}]);
app.factory('Offers', ['$http', function($http){
  var Url  = "offers.json";
  var Offers = $http.get(Url).then(function(response){
     return response.data;
  });
  return Offers;
}]);
```

in your controllers.js do something like this:

```
var SeekingCtrl = function($scope, Seeks) {
  Seeks.then(function(data){
    $scope.seeks = data;
  });
  $scope.addSeeks = function(newseeks) {
      $scope.seeks.push(newseeks);
      newseeks = "";
  };

  $scope.removeSeeks = function(seek) {
      $scope.seeks = _.without($scope.seeks, seek);
  };
};

var OfferingCtrl = function($scope, Offers) {
  Offers.then(function(data){
    $scope.offers = data;
  });
  $scope.addOffer = function(newoffer) {
      $scope.offers.push(newoffer);
      newoffer = "";
  };

  $scope.removeOffer = function(offer) {
      $scope.offers = _.without($scope.offers, offer);
  };
};
```

And don't forget to inject the `Offers` and the `Seeks` into the controllers in the app.js file like this:

```
SeekingCtrl.$inject  = ['$scope', 'Seeks'];
OfferingCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Offers'];
```

### update:

just put everything in one controller like this:

```
var MainCtrl = function($scope, Seeks, Offers) {
  Seeks.then(function(data){
    $scope.seeks = data;
  });
  Offers.then(function(data){
    $scope.offers = data;
  });
  $scope.addSeeks = function(newseeks) {
      $scope.seeks.push(newseeks);
      newseeks = "";
  };
  $scope.addOffer = function(newoffer) {
      $scope.offers.push(newoffer);
      newoffer = "";
  };
  $scope.removeSeeks = function(seek) {
      $scope.seeks = _.without($scope.seeks, seek);
  };
  $scope.removeOffer = function(offer) {
      $scope.offers = _.without($scope.offers, offer);
  };
};
```

### update 2:

```
var MainCtrl = function($scope, Seeks, Offers) {
  Seeks.then(function(data){
    $scope.seeks = data;
  });
  Offers.then(function(data){
    $scope.offers = data;
  });
  $scope.add = function(item, type) {
      $scope[type].push(item);
      item = "";
  };
  $scope.remove = function(item, type) {
      $scope[type] = _.without($scope[type], item);
  };
};
```

And the type could be seeks or offers.
For the services that's out of my league.
Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I'm really looking to reduce the number of controllers. I don't see why the two (and actually, there are more that I didn't bother showing as they're practically identical) can't be reduced to one controller.

Comment: Thanks for the update but my goal was to reduce the amount of common code. The common code is still there in your solution.

Comment: OK, for the services part there's probably a solution I can't think of it now, but for the add and remove functions you can do something like in the update 2.